# Woocommerce ajax not working endless spinning wheel

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a small shop setup using Woocommerce on Wordpress. My own VPS on nginx.

Everything was working fine but a few days ago ago Ajax is not working on checkout page.

I tried every possible way woocommerce support http://docs.woothemes.com/document/endless- loadingspinner-on-the-checkout-page/

**Chrome** console saying this:

> https://example.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)

So what I have found is when I load this `https://example.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` it goes to homepage and not loading ajax. And when I load full URLs given below it loads well.

```
https://example.com/index.php?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
https://example.com/checkout/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
```

Below is the block file for the site in question:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /home/user/example.com/public/;
    index index.php;

    access_log /home/user/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/user/example.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {

        allow all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm: fastcgi_pass
        #unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I would like woocommerce to call `wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` using full path. Any idea or suggestion for nginx config or any php/ajax workaround would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

in the php location.

and disable all plugins you have one by one.

are you mixing www.example.com and example.com?

Comment: I have disabled all the plugins except woocommerce. Tried removed that line but not worked. Only non www is being used.

Comment: whats in the server logs of php-fpm and nginx? and what happens if you opn the url directly in the browser?